# Upload base64 image to Google Cloud Storage - Expo/React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, base64, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Expo/React Native and I want to migrate some base64 images locally stored to Google Cloud Storage. I've trying to use putSting function from firebase/storage API without success so far. However, I could attemped a partial solution using [uploadString](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#uploadstring). The problem is, whenever I look at Google Cloud Storage for the uploaded files, they seems corrupted - and too long -, as the image below.

[image]

This is my code:

```
import { ref, getDownloadURL, uploadString} from "@firebase/storage";

const migratePhoto = async (newDocRef) => {

    //image example photo format 
    const photo = "data:image/jpeg;base64,4AAQSkZJRgAB....."
    const docImageRef = ref(storage, `images/${newDocRef}.jpg`)

    try {
      await uploadString(docImageRef,photo.split(',')[1],'base64', { contentType: "image/jpeg" });
      
      const downloadUrl = await getDownloadURL(docImageRef);

      return downloadUrl;

    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error',err.message)
    }
};
```

I'm not sure whether I'm managing correctly the base64 image file either uploadString is the right method.

Comment: You could check this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64739428/16531380), and also check the [example function code](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/aDJvYyNIJik/m/UvYGZeyaBgAJ).

Comment: I'm solving the issue at the frontend! The example u mentioned is a backend solution, i don't clearly see how to adapted!

Comment: Yes indeed! Thanks, I will update the ask!